# How to have real-time communication in dapp?

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, eosio-code, dfuse

How would a real-time 1v1 game work on the EOS Blockchain?
I've noticed that many of the games/gambling dapps on EOS are mostly player vs. blockchain, like EOSBet.

Could I have real-time updates to multi-indexed tables using just eos.io, or would you need a backend server for all players in the game?

I know dfuse.io provides a direct streaming service, would it be possible to use that as a part of your stack? I've looked at it, but I am confused on how to exactly use it.

Answer (score 1):

dfuse provides streaming table deltas, indeed. Start at docs.dfuse.io and join the Telegram channel for any help.

The streaming deltas is through the websocket, using "get_table_rows". It can also provide a snapshot of the whole table before starting to stream the deltas (with `fetch: true`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I could solely use dfuse.io with eos and not have to make a separate backend for something like a simple dice game?